# Objective C Struct Syntax

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

I want to understand the syntax of the struct which i have seen some where. Can some please explain the meaning of `unsigned int xyz:1;`. Is it just assigning default value to a variable `xyz`? BTW this code is in Objective C.

```
struct
        {
            unsigned int xyz:1;
    } testStruct;
```

Comment: It's called "bit field" and available from C, not only Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *bit field*. You are telling the structure that you will only be using one bit of `xyz`.

This allows the compiler to make packing optimisations.